# Python iterating through dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through a dictionary and I'm not sure how to update while looping through.

What I'm trying to do `(Simulating LFU cache)`:
Requests are taken,
Iterate through each requests one by one and count the frequency of each using dictionary.

If the dictionary holds more than 8 keys remove the lowest frequent value, if the values are all equal in frequency then delete the LOWEST key in the dictionary.

Thus Deleting the lowest key out of the current 8 and place the 9th key into it.

Then keep doing this until there is 8 values left.

Currently I have this :

```
    requests=[1, 13, 15, 1, 3, 4, 2, 12, 10, 4, 1, 15, 15, 11, 14, 7, 10, 9, 14, 5]
    lst=[] #only holds 8 ints
    def leastFrequent():
        #user inputs requests manually
            print (requests)
            freq = {} #Dictionary
        
            for i in requests:
                if i in freq.keys():
                    #Increase frequency by 1
                    freq[i] += 1
                    print("Hit", i)
                else:
                    #If not set frequency to 1
                    freq[i] = 1
                    print("Miss", i)
            #I want to move my while loop inside this i think?? but i get errors with it being a dictionary

           freq = sorted(freq.items(), key=lambda k: k[0])#places dictionary into list of lists
           freq.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])#sort in order
           print("Converted frequency:",str(freq))
        
            while len(freq)>8:
                print("Size greater than 8..\n",str(freq[0]))
                del freq[0]#atm this just deletes the first value printed since it should be the lowest
                if len(freq)<=8:
                    break
        #i then move elements[0] into a final list to be printed
            lst=[item[0] for item in freq] 
            print ("\nPrinting final list")        
            print(lst)
            
    leastFrequent()
```

The problem with this is that it doesnt delete while iterating through one by one, it counts all the terms first then deletes the lowest ones.

Which leads to an incorrect output:

```
 [11, 12, 13, 4, 10, 14, 1, 15]
```

Expected output:

```
[1, 13, 15, 4, 12, 11, 14, 5]
```

Doesnt matter about order and i want to try using no librarys in this.

Sorry if it sounds confusing im new to programming and im trying to learn how to use dictionaries and lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something from your description, but following your logic I get the same output.

I believe your code is wrong, looping after the counting - but perhaps in this case it oddly doesn't change the output.

```
requests=[1, 13, 15, 1, 3, 4, 2, 12, 10, 4, 1, 15, 15, 11, 14, 7, 10, 9, 14, 5]

freq = {}

for r in requests:
    r = str(r)
    if r in freq:
        freq[r]+=1
        print(f'Hit {r}')
    else:
        freq[r]=1
        print(f'Miss {r}')
    if len(freq.keys()) > 8:
        # Get list of keys that share the lowest frequency
        k = [int(k) for k, v in freq.items() if v == min(freq.values())]
        print(f'Requests sharing the lowest frequency of {min(freq.values())} -> {k}')
        print(f'Dropping lowest request value -> {min(k)}')
        del freq[str(min(k))]
        
print([int(x) for x in freq.keys()])
```

Final Output

```
[1, 13, 15, 4, 12, 10, 11, 14]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help ill try carrying it on but this is great thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is pretty confusing, but as I understood we have the income of key:value pairs and variable that is saved as dictionary(hash map) and you want to keep highest frequency or highest(key) if frequency has same value. To have my suggestion in short - u just want to recreate dictionary every single time it is updated. Let's take your code:

```
# creates dictionary out of frequencies based on the input list
def simulating_list(req, req_list):
    req_list[req] = 1 if req not in req_list else req_list[req]+1

# 1.takes items of the list and sorts by frequency;
# 2.takes a slice of the list starting from 8th element from the end
# 3.reverses the list(just to look nice, dictionaries nowadays displyed ordered)
# 4.creates new dictionary out of list of lists


def filter_eight(req_list):
    return dict(sorted(req_list.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[-8:][::-1])


# Your request lists
requests = [1, 13, 15, 1, 3, 4, 2, 12, 10,
            4, 1, 15, 15, 11, 14, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 3, 4, 2, 34,  23, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 3, 12, 3, 4, 2, 3, 7, 10, 9, 14, 5]
# data base
req_data_base = {}
# generator inside the list will execute
[simulating_list(i, req_data_base) for i in requests]

print(filter_eight(req_data_base))
# Displays dictionary with key = request, value= frequency
# If you want to display it differently its up to you
# {3: 9, 4: 8, 2: 7, 1: 6, 12: 4, 5: 3, 15: 3, 14: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun(requests):
    freq={}
    for i in requests:
        if i in freq:
            freq[i]+=1
            print("hit",i)
        else:
            freq[i]=1
            print("miss",i)
        if len(freq)>8:
            to_remove = min(freq,key=lambda k:(freq[k],k))
            print("to remove",to_remove,"from",freq)
            del freq[to_remove]
    return freq
```

this is similar to Chris's, but without converting thing to string back and for, the other thing is to get the element to delete it use the key function of `min`, and we use as comparison-key the pair (value,key) using the feature that tuple are orderable and their order is given by their value position base, so if they have the same value (or frequency in this case) in the first position, check for its second position which is the our dictionary key (or a given request)

```
>>> requests=[1, 13, 15, 1, 3, 4, 2, 12, 10, 4, 1, 15, 15, 11, 14, 7, 10, 9, 14, 5]
>>> result=fun(requests)
miss 1
miss 13
miss 15
hit 1
miss 3
miss 4
miss 2
miss 12
miss 10
hit 4
hit 1
hit 15
hit 15
miss 11
to remove 2 from {1: 3, 13: 1, 15: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2, 2: 1, 12: 1, 10: 1, 11: 1}
miss 14
to remove 3 from {1: 3, 13: 1, 15: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2, 12: 1, 10: 1, 11: 1, 14: 1}
miss 7
to remove 7 from {1: 3, 13: 1, 15: 3, 4: 2, 12: 1, 10: 1, 11: 1, 14: 1, 7: 1}
hit 10
miss 9
to remove 9 from {1: 3, 13: 1, 15: 3, 4: 2, 12: 1, 10: 2, 11: 1, 14: 1, 9: 1}
hit 14
miss 5
to remove 5 from {1: 3, 13: 1, 15: 3, 4: 2, 12: 1, 10: 2, 11: 1, 14: 2, 5: 1}
>>> result
{1: 3, 13: 1, 15: 3, 4: 2, 12: 1, 10: 2, 11: 1, 14: 2}
>>> list(result)
[1, 13, 15, 4, 12, 10, 11, 14]
>>>
```

(also notice that  dictionaries iterate over their keys be default, so is not really necessary to call .keys)